# how to get twitter app name from api keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I don't know if this is the right place and I don't even know how to get started but is it possible to get the twitter app name as a variable from the keys, like

```
Consumerkey = ''
CosumerSecret = ''
AcessKey = ''
AcessSecret = ''
```

is it possible to get the twitter app name from these keys if not, thanks anyway I just can't find a way straight googling

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to get the Twitter App name from just these details.